# SNS -> Lambda: What happens when Lambda throttles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda function subscribed to an SNS topic. I wonder, what will happen when that lambda function is throttled?

Will SNS ensure that the message is delivered later?
Will the message got dropped on the floor after x retries?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In short, delivery will be re-tired three times, after which your message will be sent to the DLQ for your Lambda (if you have one).

You can read up about this in the [lambda throttling documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html#throttling-behavior) and [event sources documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-sns).